# Internet is dropping in and out only when using a lot of data

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, network-adapter

**Current Setup:**

- ONT Modem with fibre connecting to wall
- Router connecting to the modem
- Wifi devices (phones, ipads, apple tv)
- Desktop computer connected to the router via ethernet (no wifi available)

  - Custom built by Digital Storm
  - Processor: Intel Core i9-10850K (5.2 GHz Turbo) (20-Thread) (10-Core) 3.6 GHz
  - Motherboard: ASUS Prime Z490-P / MSI Z490-A Pro (Intel Z490 Chipset) (Up to 2x PCI-E Devices) (No SLI Support)
  - System Memory: 32GB DDR4 3200MHz
  - Windows 11

**What's Happening:**

- All internet drops in and out (including ethernet and wifi for all devices)
- Internet does not drop when I am not using the desktop
- Internet does not drop when bypassing the router and connecting the ethernet directly to the modem
  Internet seems to only drop when I am using too much data on the desktop (ie. start playing music on Pandora, watching YouTube videos, or downloading a huge video file)
- Modem lights: power, broadband, and service stay lit all the time whether the internet is out or connected
- When getting disconnected, only the ethernet light on the modem turns off and the router completely reboots

**What We Have Tried:**

- Unplugged the modem and router for 30+ seconds
- Called ISP, they tried the following:

  - Checked for outages
  - Checked that the router firmware was up to date
  - Swapped out the ethernet cable that connects the modem to the router
  - Swapped out the router many times, tried 4 different models in total (all supplied by the ISP - Calix brand), with the last/current one being their "more powerful" top of the line model
  - Swapped out the modem
  - Swapped out the ethernet cable to the computer
  - Plugged in iPad via ethernet adapter into router and tried triggering a drop by playing YouTube videos; did not drop internet
  - Suggested it might be NIC card on computer
- Logged into router settings and turned off firewall, turned back on when it didn't fix it
- Called my employer's IT company, they tried the following:

  - Had me plug the modem and router into a different outlet in case it was an issue with the power
  - Checked that network drivers are up to date
  - Checked that Windows 11 is up to date
  - Checked for malware via Windows Defender and Malwarebytes
  - Network reset, reboot; seemed to last longer, but eventually failed again after I got off the phone with them
- Ran network commands  to manually reset the TCP/IP stack, release and renew the IP address, and flush and reset the DNS client resolver cache
- Realized that it doesn't seem to drop when I'm not using too much data; tested it after a couple of hours of just browsing the internet without fail, then tried to download a video and it immediately disconnected

[EDIT]
**Update:**

- Contacted computer manufacturer (Digital Storm) support, they tried the following:

  - Replaced Windows recommended NIC driver with Realtek Ethernet Controller Driver
  - Updated Intel Chipset drivers
  - Used DISM to repair Windows Image
  - After that I was able to download the same large video I was testing previously and didn’t lose internet
  - Noticed an issue with Windows Update; even though it says it is up to date, the “Check for Updates” button is greyed out and no updates have been done since Windows 11 was installed in February 2023
  - Checked service properties and registry
  - Ran Windows Update troubleshooter, found an issue, but no option to fix it
  - Tech is not very familiar with Windows 11, so they said I might need to talk to someone else about the Windows Update issue, but to test if the internet drops first
- Updated regedit

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`

    - Deleted `NoAutoUpdate`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`

    - Deleted `DisableWindowsUpdateAccess`
    - Deleted `SetDisableUXWUAccess`
    - After restart, they show up again, cannot figure out how to make it permanent; also tried modifying them and setting to 0, same result
- Confirmed not in Windows Insider Program
- Ran Windows Updates manually via `USOClient StartInteractiveScan`

  - Found and installed 11 driver updates, but no feature or quality updates found
- Gpedit.msc => Disabled `Settings Page Visibility` in Group Policy and `Show Only Specified Control Panel Items`
- Forced updating policy via command: `gpupdate /force`
- Still cutting off, but not every time I try to overload it; killed the internet on boot
- Purchased a wifi USB adapter and tried to load music on wifi from desktop; killed the internet after loading pandora in browser; confirmed not a NIC card issue

  - TP-Link AC1300 Dual Antennas High-Gain Wireless USB Adapter, Model: Archer T4U Plus
- Purchased an ethernet to USB C adapter, plugged the ethernet into my MacBook Pro; no issues with the internet, can load music and browse internet just fine; confirmed not a router issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a better router. Get one where you can set priorities for network traffic. If you do get a better router with 2.5 Gb or 10 Gb ports then why not upgrade your PC's NIC to match.

One thing you can do to test the NIC, is get a cheap USB to ethernet adapter or a USB to wifi adaptor. This way you can test to see if the NIC in your PC is the issue. If the NIC is the issue you can replace it.

There is a possibility that a program or virus on your PC is hogging up all the bandwidth. If the router you have can set priorities for different ports or devices, you can lower the priority of the PC. That will slow down the traffic from your PC and the other device on your network shouldn't be effected anymore.
You can also try to boot off a USB stick that has anther operating system installed on it. If the issue goes away after this then you know it's an issue with the OS or an application on the OS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I purchased a wifi adapter for the desktop and still killed the internet, confirming it's not a NIC card issue. I also purchased a USB-C to ethernet adapter to test the ethernet on my MacBook Pro, and there were no issues with the internet, confirming it's not an issue with my router. I just updated my original question with everything else we have tried. My employer's IT company is trying to figure it out and said they'd be calling me back later today.

Comment: Is any of the network equipment realy hot?  I'm asking because if the modem or router is overheating it may slow down the internet speed or reboot. 
To ensure it's not a power issue, plugin the equipment into a power strip that can clean up your power. I higher end power strip or most UPS, will ensure you have consistent power. Another method to do this would be to a power meter / watt meter, between the equipment and the wall outlet. This is to see if there are any spikes or interruptions.

Comment: You mentioned you have a mac book. If I'm reading your description right, this is only happening with your windows 11 PC. If you can't make your internet drop when using your MAC, then your win 11 PC is the issue.

Comment: Nothing is getting hot. Yes, it's definitely the Win 11 PC. Our IT company is going to try one other fix tomorrow and if that doesn't work we might try reinstalling windows.